# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistenceUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on REST server and learning EJB\hibernate at the same time. When service call DAO I faced with an issue that it can not find my persistence unit.

```
@Stateless
public class HotelDAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = Constants.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
private EntityManager em;


public List<HotelsEntity> getAll() {
// TODO complete me
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<HotelsEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(HotelsEntity.class);
    Root<HotelsEntity> root = criteria.from(HotelsEntity.class);
    criteria.select(root);
    TypedQuery<HotelsEntity> resultQuery = em.createQuery(criteria);
    return resultQuery.getResultList();
}
}
```

In this case I get "Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName persistenceUnit"

Then I try this:

```
@Stateless
public class HotelDAO {

public List<HotelsEntity> getAll() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // TODO complete me
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<HotelsEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(HotelsEntity.class);
    Root<HotelsEntity> root = criteria.from(HotelsEntity.class);
    criteria.select(root);
    TypedQuery<HotelsEntity> resultQuery = em.createQuery(criteria);
    return resultQuery.getResultList();
}
}
```

In this case I get "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistenceUnit".

I checl similar issues at the stackoverflow:

- persitence.xml under META-INF
- DAO is injected into EJB
- provider is mentioned in persistence.xml
- I don't use Spring

Do you have any gueses?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/HospitalityDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.example.model.AmmenitiesEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.HotelPropertyEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.HotelsEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.InventoriesEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.ReservationEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.RoomEntity</class>
    <class>com.example.model.RoomPropertyEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="dbroot"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: do you have multiple projects? or one single EJB project?

Comment: On the first question: it is a single project/ The second question I don't understand: I use EJB in my app if it what do you mean

Comment: So you have a single project containing EJB and hibernate and persistence.xml right? Can you post the structure of your project? Another question... did you also verify if the JNDI "jdbc/HospitalityDataSource" is available in your server?

Comment: Update wit the structure. JNDI name was defined in persitence xml and then this name was added on the server (glassfish)/ Am right that I am free to choose the JNDI name or it should depend on some thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, I think persistence.xml must be in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: You are right, but now it thrown java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider. I just moved xml in resource\META-INF

Comment: Do you have the hibernate-entitymanager dependency in your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, I have:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: No idea... is the dependency packaged in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I don't have this dir WEB-INF/lib

Comment: The dir is created when you package the WAR. Extract the WAR and look if the dependency is in.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't have it!

Comment: I made this dependecy as a "compile" and it works. Thank for your help, Carles! Could you please share your thoughts what is it can be?

Comment: I have no idea, I'd need more info. Maybe other dependency of the pom.xml have the hibernate-entitymanager as inner dependency with provided scope...